# Linking a lib statically in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker

Probably I am missing here something but that is my first time on Windows that I need to link a lib statically so that the executable won't be dependent on a dll.I do it with LIBPNG.

I do it like this:

1. I added libpng headers : C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories
2. Added library directory to the linker: Linker - > General ->
   Additional Library Directories
3. Added linker additional dependencies:Linker -> Input

Compile the exe ok.When calling it I am getting :

> "The program can't start because libpng16.dll is missing from your
>   computer."

Which means libpng hasn't compiled into the executable.How do I fix that without [reference the whole pnglib project code into my executable project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85391/Microsoft-Visual-C-Static-and-Dynamic-Libraries#ReferencingTheStaticLibrary)?

Comment: "libpng16.dll" in the error indicates that this is *not* a static library, but a dynamic linked library. You might be fine if you just copy the dll to the same folder as your executable. Otherwise, you need to make sure the library does support static linking and then link against the *correct* .lib file for that.

Comment: @crashmstr I don't want to do this.I want libpng to be compiled into the final program.

Comment: I edited my comment to include a statement that you need to make sure: 1. libpng supports static linking and 2. you link against the correct .lib that is the static library and not the one that "points" to the dll.

Comment: @crashmstr  1. - is what I am trying to figure out now but I want to make also sure my VS setup is correct.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows a .lib is a library file, usually this simply contains code that loads a dll, looksup the exported functions and provides wrappers to them. But, you can build the lib differently so that instead of these wrapper stubs, it contains the actual binary code. The operation and structure of the .lib is the same - what code it contains depends on how its built.

So, if you've built libpng16 as a 'dynamic' lib/dll pair then you will need the dll part when you deploy it. If you built it as a 'static' lib only, then you'll get what you want.

The point is - you need to build the lib in the format you want in the first place. It is not possible to take a lib/dll pair and convert it into a static lib, nor is it possible to merge a dll into your executable. (well, not possible after you've built it - perfectly possibly if you change the lib's settings and recompile to produce in static lib form, of course)

Comment: hmm,not I see,I need then to figure out how to build libpng statically.

Comment: yes. Use [Lib.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx) instead of Link.exe to generate the lib.

Comment: I am not sure I am getting you.

Comment: follow the hyperlink, it tells you the settings to use to build a static lib.

Comment: the one under "Lib.exe". Change your browser underline hyperlink colours!

Comment: Where is "lib.exe" written?Are you serious?

Comment: @MichaelIV. The link "Lib.exe" is in gbjbaand's first comment.

Comment: lib.exe is part of Visual Studio's compiler suite along with cl.exe and link.exe amongst others. However, I'm just thinking that maybe it was not shipped with the express versions. Maybe that's a problem for you.

Comment: The problem is probably that my libpng compilation setup is not as for static lib